# make div to behave like a sticky when scroll is reached to certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a div elements contains dynamic text upto words (10 to 250).Now i have to make another div to behave like sticky when user reached to button of first div which contains plain text.Here is how i am trying so far .

```
   <div></div> //which contains plain text , stick to be available once user scroll to end of this.
   <div class="scroller_anchor"></div> // sticky to become when user reached to this div.
   <div> </div> // which one to behaves like sticky.
   //Here is code
   if(($(document).scrollTop() <$(".scroller_anchor").offset().top  ) ){
    $('.scroller_anchor').css('height', '0px');
    $('.scroller').css({
       'position': 'relative'
    });


  }else if ($(document).scrollTop() > ($(".scroller_anchor").offset().top )){
      $('.scroller').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '0px'
        });
        $('.scroller_anchor').css('height', '50px');

  }
```

With this everything is working fine except , div becomes sticky only after user scroll something below firs div.If i use `$(document).scrollTop() <$(".scroller_anchor").offset().top -100` it works for some text (say upto 75 words) . How do make this `factor (-100 , -220)` etc dynamic .

Answer (score 0):

Calculate `scrollHeight`  which behaves like a factor in your case , here is how do calculate.

```
var scrollHeight =  window.innerHeight * (window.innerHeight / document.body.offsetHeight);
```

Different browser behaves slightly different. Replace `100` by `scrollHeight` . Will might work.